# PostgreSQL - Adding column to table and updating it with value from other table in one statement does not update the column

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a ddl to add a column to one table and fill it with values from another newly created table depending on a boolean value from the updated table.
So I create the new table first, fill it with the necessary values, then add the column to the existing table. Next I update this column but this update is not executed when I try to do all in one transaction.

If I execute the update statement seperately after the creation of the table and new column it works fine, so I know there is nothing wrong with my update statement.

I do not understand why it is not executed when I run all statements in one transaction. Can anybody help?

```
-- Create the table for the sub types
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS framework."UserGroupSubType_S";
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
    framework."UserGroupSubTypes"
(
    "UserGroupSubTypeId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "UserGroupSubType" CHARACTER VARYING(50) NOT NULL,
    "Updated" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    CONSTRAINT
        "UserGroupSubTypeId_P"
        PRIMARY KEY ("UserGroupSubTypeId"),
    CONSTRAINT
        "UserGroupSubTypes_UserGroupSubType"
        UNIQUE ("UserGroupSubType")
)
WITH
    (
    OIDS = FALSE
);

-- Fill the table with the sub types
INSERT INTO framework."UserGroupSubTypes"
VALUES 
    (NEXTVAL('"UserGroupSubType_S"'), 'CustomerDefined', NOW()),
    (NEXTVAL('"UserGroupSubType_S"'), 'Mandatory', NOW()),
    (NEXTVAL('"UserGroupSubType_S"'), 'GeneralAdmin', NOW()),
    (NEXTVAL('"UserGroupSubType_S"'), 'Buyer', NOW())
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

-- Add the column to the table "UserGroups"
ALTER TABLE framework."UserGroups" ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS "UserGroupSubTypeId" INTEGER;

-- Update the column with the correct value
UPDATE framework."UserGroups"
SET "UserGroupSubTypeId" = (CASE
    WHEN "IsMandatory" = TRUE
        THEN (SELECT "UserGroupSubTypeId" FROM framework."UserGroupSubTypes" WHERE "UserGroupSubType" = 'Mandatory')
    WHEN "IsMandatory" = FALSE
        THEN (SELECT "UserGroupSubTypeId" FROM framework."UserGroupSubTypes" WHERE "UserGroupSubType" = 'CustomerDefined')
    END);
```

I have tried other ways of updating, like setting the default value to 1 and then only updating the ones that need another value, but nothing seems to work.
The column does not get updated ever.

Comment: First why not `"UserGroupSubTypeId" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY`, same for `UNIQUE` on `"UserGroupSubType"`.  Second I do not see `BEGIN/COMMIT` indicating that this all one transaction? Third, if this is indeed in a transaction are you looking at the updated table from another session before the `COMMIT`? If so you will not see the changes. Fourth, do the Postgres logs show any errors while this is happening?

Comment: About the primary key and the unique constraint, this is just the way it is set up in the company, so I can't change that. The begin commit are handled in a different part of the code, so I am pretty sure these statements are all processed in the same transactions.
I also tried these in PgAdmin, with the same result.
About your third point, if this was the case, would I not see any of the changes? I do see the new table, I do see the new column, but the column values are still NULL

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: I know, but sometimes you gotta follow the rules of the company :p

Answer (score 0):

Apparently PgAdmin doesn't handle a group of selected statements as one transaction.
Thanks to Adrain's comment I tried adding

```
BEGIN;
---
---
COMMIT;
```

around the statements and that solved the problem. The column is now filled correctly with the values from the newly created table.

Thank you Adrian for your help

Comment: Glad it worked. In pgAdmin  I'm assuming you are using the Query Tool. If so next to the Execute icon there should be an icon with a \/ mark. Click on that and see if Auto Commit and/or Auto Rollback are checked.  Sounds like Auto Commit was/is not checked.

Comment: I will check first thing on monday, thanks for the tip